Passing list to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in ExternalProject_Add
When passing list of flags to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS in ExternalProject_Add configure command, the list becomes formatted and all semicolons are replaced with spaces. My goal is to define preprocessor macros for library imported by ExternalProject_Add. Encapsulating the list in quotes works, but it is passed to the compiler as the exact same string instead of preprocessor macros. Using target_compile_definitions on ExternalLibrary throws error saying something about ExternalLibrary not being built target. Is there a way around the ExternalProject_Add formatting or another way to define preprocessor macros for ExternalLibrary imported by ExternalProject_Add?
Example code:
ExternalProject_Add(
    ExternalLibrary
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/someone/examplelibrary.git
    INSTALL_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/External/ExternalLibrary/install
    PREFIX ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/External/ExternalLibrary

    CONFIGURE_COMMAND cmake <SOURCE_DIR> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<INSTALL_DIR> -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-DMACRO1;-DMACRO2
    #-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-DMACRO1 -DMACRO2" is the only format I found that doesn't throw CMake error, but doesn't work with the compiler.
    BUILD_COMMAND cmake --build <BINARY_DIR> --config ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
    INSTALL_COMMAND cmake --install <BINARY_DIR> --prefix <INSTALL_DIR> --config ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    PATCH_COMMAND ""

    INSTALL_BYPRODUCTS <INSTALL_DIR>/lib/examplelibrary.lib
)


quote it "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-DMACRO1;-DMACRO2"? is the only format do not quote pa"rt". quote the whole thing "part".

Figured this out just minutes before your comment, but thank you. :D
